# Pagination is not working on category.php with 3 Query

Tags: wordpress

I have 3 Query's on category.php and I want pagination for all loop, but unfortunately the first loop is working only. I have figured out that its getting problem because of offset because when I remove offset it works well but I badly need offsetting post. How can I rectify my Query? Here is my code below.

```
<div class="row" id="CatContent">
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
    <div class="leadnewsboxtitle">
        <?php 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
        $postquery = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'cat' => $cat_id,
            'paged' => $paged   
        ));
        while($postquery->have_posts()) : $postquery->the_post(); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
            <p><?php read_more(25); ?> ...</p>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 twoboxlist">
    <?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
    $postquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'offset' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged
    ));
    while($postquery->have_posts()) : $postquery->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="category-news-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="category-news-output">
    <?php 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
    $postquery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'offset' => 3,
        'paged' => $paged                               
    ));
    while($postquery->have_posts()) : $postquery->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="category-news-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

```
<?php the_posts_pagination(
array(
'prev_text' => __( 'Prev', 'btimes' ),
'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'btimes' ),
'screen_reader_text' => ' '
) ); ?>
```

Thanks in advance any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple queries on a page they can get mixed up, especially since you are using the same PHP variable names for each query. Try adding this after each query (after the "endwhile"):

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but still facing problem. I think its because of offset. Can you please give me any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution without multiple query.

```
<div class="row" id="CatContent">
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while(have_posts()):the_post();
        if($i==0) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                <div class="leadnewsboxtitle">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                    <p><?php read_more(25); ?> ...</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 twoboxlist">
        <?php }elseif($i==1) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==2) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==3) { ?>
            </div>
            <div class="category-news-output">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="category-news-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==4) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==5) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==6) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==7) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==8) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==9) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==10) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }elseif($i==11) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="category-news-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
    $i++;
endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
'prev_text' => __( 'আগের খবর', 'btimes' ),
'next_text' => __( 'পরের খবর', 'btimes' ),
'screen_reader_text' => ' '
```

) ); ?>